# Destroy a Planet inside a black hole?

Tags: planets, weapons, science-fiction, black-holes

Imagine a race whom have mastered the knowledge of black holes, at least a bit.
They've found a way survive, with their planet intact, inside the gravitation of the black hole without getting destroyed by it. (I know it is not possible for humans but in my fictional universe there are species which understand the universe a lot better then we do.)

Is there a way for the enemy to destroy the planets inside the black hole? I ask because all missiles or some cannon like the death star would be destroyed by the black hole and would the black hole also grow?

Let me explain the following picture: 3 planets are in the gravity pull of the black-hole but around each planet there is a safe-zone created by a much more advanced race, they even have something like wormholes in the safe-zone so they can leave the black-hole's pull. There is no way to enter the wormhole for other species.
If a planet gets sucked in by the black-hole, would the dismembered planet collide with the planets?
I imagine the parts of the dismembered planet would rotate in a way people do in a funnel slide. I hope you grasp what I am trying to say.

Edit: JDługosz helped me understanding the horizon, please read his answer and make new suggestions.

1. How can they find the localization of these planets?
2. Which weapon would be enough to destroy them and what is the best way to destroy all three planets at once (So they can't prepare a defence)?

[image]

Would something like this hit the planets? But— I mean something with physical form, planets or a sun, but in the form of the example. [Example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Black_hole_lensing_web.gif)

Comment: «something like this hit the planets»  would a drawing of lensing effects hit the planets?  Whaaaaaat?

Comment: The animated gif you linked to is an example of lensing effect of a black hole on a background star field. You may want to play with this to get some sense of what happens due to relativity: http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/

Comment: If they can enter end leave a black hole it means they operate outside our physical universe and/or possibly can move through higher dimensional space, so they can pretty much do anything and survive any attack you can think of.

Comment: I can't parse what you wrote there.

Comment: @JDługosz I meant to say i just like the way the light moves inside the black whole, i just want to know if a sun enter the horizion will it look like in the example?

Comment: Where is the event horizon? Since a worm hole appears no different than a black hole I suggest your only way to escape the intense gravity well is actually falling into the blackhole.

Comment: Why does your enemy want to destroy the planets in the black hole? Since nothing can ever come out of the black hole, it's already effectively as if the planets were destroyed -- they can never have any effect of any kind on the enemy.

Comment: @MikeScott they have wormholes to escape through.

Comment: @JDługosz Not if the question doesn't say they do -- that would be an important parameter.

Comment: It said exactly that when I read it originally.  Still does: «they even have wormholes in the safe-zone so they can leave the black-hole's pull.»

Comment: The premise is incorrect, since there are no stable orbits inside of the black hole's event horizon, i.e. everything within must be falling into the center (though it could be spiraling around the center).  I suggest you read up on the innermost stable circular orbit (for a non-rotating black hole this is three times the Schwarzschild radius).  I also agree that give the premise, there is no way to give a true science-based answer.

Comment: This question has way too much handwaving in the premise to be answerable. "There's a race that *somehow* avoids the fundamental problems with remaining near a black hole indefinitely, and can also *somehow* keep everyone else from using their wormholes. What happens when another object hits the unexplained planetary shells?

Comment: @Snyder005 Maybe not: https://www.technologyreview.com/s/423608/planets-could-orbit-singularities-inside-black-holes/

Comment: It sounds like you ought to “accept” the answer you noted as clarifying your concept, and post a new question. It doesn't make sence to add followups as existing answers are for the original question.

Comment: @JDługosz yes you are right.

Comment: @zeeman those orbits are likely derived from an extended Kerr coordinate system which is unstable solution, as well as suffering from the hand-waving away of many causality concerns.  Within the realm of science fiction, but it definitely raises more questions in regards to the physics.

Comment: @Snyder005 I don't actually know any GR (well, except for the maximal aging principle and that there and that, in general, two body orbits aren't stable) but what does the paper referenced in the article mean by "Stable periodic orbits inside black holes"?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the question is *irrelevant* as the planet in question has no means (nor time) by which to interact with the rest of the universe, so what's the point?

Comment: @Draco18s how can you know it? We dont know whats inside a blackhole?

Comment: @Xxy It's right there in the name: event horizon.  Nothing inside the event horizon can ever effect anything outside the event horizon because the escape velocity exceeds the speed of light.  The only way would be through phelotinium or handwavium.  At which point you can do whatever the frack you want.

Comment: Ah, found the video I was thinking about. I'd forgotten what channel it was on. [What Happens Inside a Black Hole?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNaEBbFbvcY)

Comment: @zeeman I only skimmed the paper, the author calculates stable orbits assuming a black hole interior is represented by a maximally extended Kerr-Newman metric.  Caveats: Black holes are eternal and are connected to white holes.  Non-rotating black holes must be charged to have any orbits.  Planets are treated as point particles (or point planets).  The coordinates they use may not correspond to what "physical coordinates" (e.g. Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates for a maximally extended Schwarzschild black hole).  The author admits causality violations may exist.

Comment: Sir, I have no choice except to upvote your amazing question.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to understand better how the *event horizon* works.  It is a point of no return.  Your implicit idea of it being a shell that destroys anything that passes is simply wrong.

From [physicist Matt Strassler’s blog](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/relativity-space-astronomy-and-cosmology/black-holes/black-hole-information-paradox-an-introduction/):

> A horizon is not an object, but a place beyond which escape is impossible. A famous analogy is to a boat approaching a waterfall, in an increasingly fast current. Once the boat passes a curve of no-return (see Figure 3), its engine will be unable to fight the current, and it will inevitably go over the waterfall. But the captain of the boat will not notice anything when crossing this curve; it is just an ordinary part of the river, whose importance will only become clear when the captain seeks to escape disaster. Similarly, in general relativity you will notice nothing when crossing the horizon; it’s only when you try to escape the black hole that you will discover that — oops! — you went too close
>
> [image: picture]

A missile can enter the event horizon from the outside and hit the planet inside.  They just need some way to aim when they can’t see in.

You can find examples of general relativity scenarios along the line of Alice falls into a black hole, and some time later Bob jumps in after her and can still rendezvous. Similarly, missiles entering the black hole can target the planets inside.

Comment: Ok i get the idea, but imagine entering the horizon with a spacecraft, ok you cant escape anymore but can you just fly in the middle? I think not the mass g forces would rip your ship in pieces that is what i mean with can will you attack something, so strong even "bending" light?

Comment: You can't just fly around anywhere: some orbits are not possible. Think about it how you can’t move fast enough to orbit the singularity, but have *some* choice as to your path before eventually crashing to the center.  GR is more complex, but you can see the basic idea.

Comment: You are thinking of tidal forces?  You don’t feel g forces like you are supposing. In free fall you feel none; to resist falling you feel a crushing force.  Now tides are a problem, but this BH is the mass of galaxies for planets to exist inside the horizon; the forces will be smaller.  Asimov wrote how the entire observale universe might be a black hole!  And we have no trouble moving around; just (if that were the case) could not escape from the megacluster of galaxies.  The larger the BH, the lower the average density.

Comment: Ok but if there is no such strong force that weapons or anything would get ripped of, what expects you inside of a blackhole and also in the center? I know we cant send a drone in because no information can leafe the horizion but will you just be in the center and then wait till you starve because the gravity is so strong so you cant leave?

Comment: In this case Xxy is right, after a certain distance, things experience spaghettification, they will get completely obliterated and made a nice string of atoms. The effect is inversely proportional to the square of distance from the black hole. Thus if missiles are not getting destroyed, move your planets close to the center. This effect has no relation to the event horizon.

Comment: If you know where the safe zone planets are located inside the BH, it's possible send in missiles to destroy them. The missiles can be self-guided by AIs for the final run to hit their targets. The missile warheads need to be able to disable the safe zones. The BH will do the rest. Even if spaghettification affects the missiles, they can be aimed to ensure the spray of particles will hit the safe zone planets.

Comment: It's straightforward and direct, the physics supports missiles targeting the planets inside the black hole. Black holes can't act as a shields, even for planets snug in their safe zones. Plus one for cutting through the fog of physics.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu I'm assuming the BH is large enough that planets can exist inside it with a minimum of handwaving.  Missiles are much smaller.  What is magical "safe zone" means is not really described and I think the OP's mental image of what the space is like "inside" was quite wrong, so he may modify exactly what that "safe zone" means as he refines the model.

Comment: Question states safe zones and whole bh thingy is for protection, so I would assume that it is 100% handwaved. I would say some sort of anti-graviton field to overcome the gravity of bh.

Comment: Your edit helped me a lot, i understand how this work and i get what you mean, so they just need to find the localiations of the planet because they cant see something because there is no light. Thanks but know i need something how to find this localization and also i still want to hear ideas of destroying something with my wrong vision of the black hole.

Comment: @Xxy the gravity effects get stronger as the object gets further past the event horizon.  The time dilation effects get stronger too.  And the velocity relative to the center, from the point of view of an external observer, approaches zero.  So anything that enters the even horizon is doomed from an observer's POV, but the actual cessation of existence of that item will likely take millennia.

Comment: «i still want to hear ideas of destroying something with my wrong vision of the black hole»  that's not possible since we don't know what you were thinking your bh was like.  And it’s completely made up so answers can just make up anything too.  What you need, in a new question, is to **describe** your “exclusion zone” security field in detail and ask for ways around it.   I’ll get you started with that shortly.

Comment: @Xxy [see here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/4000/885) and good luck to you.

Comment: There's a problem with this. The event horizon isn't just a black boundary that you can't backtrack over - Time itself seems to stop at the event horizon. The space-time curvature - and thus time dilation - inside the black hole is so extreme that objects inside a black hole cannot meaningfully be considered part of our universe. Does the missile reach the center? Nobody knows, but as far as our timeline is concerned everything is at a standstill inside the black hole - It's almost like time and the objects inside no longer exist.

Comment: People who know GR and are pros commonly state how Alice doesn't experience anything special upon crossing the horizon.

Comment: @JDługosz: Tidal effects are irrelevant here. For a large enough black hole (galactic mass), at the event horizon there are only negligible tidal effects. As others have stated, space is locally flat for the observer. Getting back to the OP, the whole thing would be irrelevant if it weren't for the magical wormholes: whatever is inside the event horizon is beyond our universe's timeline, past its ultimate future: for a distant observer, it literally takes forever for anything to fall past the event horizon.

Comment: "Your implicit idea of [the event horizon] being a shell that destroys anything that passes is simply wrong." you obviously haven't heard of [black hole firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(physics)).

Comment: «For a large enough black hole (galactic mass), at the event horizon there are only negligible tidal effects» yes, that’s what I’ve said.  E.g. third comment on this post.

Comment: Hmm, but you would notice right? Say we divide the area of a blackhole into two pieces. One in which my head resides and which is farther away from the singularity, the other in which the rest of my body resides, which is closer to the singularity. Then the blood in my body can only flow from my head to the rest of my body, but not up. Just like sending electrical signals up, it wouldn't work. 

The same when you put your arm through the event horizon. The feeling in your arm would directly be cut off, nothing comes out anymore.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks very interesting point!

Answer (score 19):

You should watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNaEBbFbvcY) about black holes.  Your premise is so nonsensical for General Relativity that you might as well be asking "why is the moon made of cheese?"  Um... its not.  Planets cannot orbit inside the event horizon, the only direction inside the EH is towards the singularity at the center.  Everything inside will not retain a form recognizable to us.  As @AnoE pointed out below, this applies after you are close enough to the singularity for tidal forces to tear you into a thin stream of particles, known as [spagetiffication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification).  However, just because an object can enter an event horizon and not be shredded immediately doesn't mean stable orbits are remotely possible.

Thus, the answers to your questions are actually trivial:

> 1. How to find the localization of these planets.

The mass of these planets, along with all the rest of the mass of the black hole, is located at the infinitely small singularity at the center.

> 2. Which weapon would be enough to destroy them and what is the best way to destroy all three planets at once. (So they cant prepare)

Nothing needs to be done, they are already destroyed.

You can't make this science-based, as your tag wants**.  The only way to make your premise make sense is to move to an entirely different universe with different laws of physics, because Einstein, Hawking, and others have proven this impossible.

**Note: the question was tagged as `science-based` when I first answered this.  That has since been removed.  I'm not updating my answer since people seem to find it helpful, however the changed context makes it less relevant to the question.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Either go full fantasy style, ignore laws of physics and come up with whatever you like, since you already broke the rules, or play along the rules from the beginning. There are too many questions like "X is impossible, but I somehow allow it. How to achieve Y (which is next to impossible) without allowing it?"

Comment: But they somehow have created a way to maintain orbit while protecting themselves. Perhaps they found a way to distort physics as we know it? We dont know everything. What if relativity can be altered?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck GR is incomplete to be sure, but we have a good understanding of where its weaknesses are, and the extreme curvature of spacetime inside the event horizon is not one of them (what exactly is happening to the matter inside, is still an open question).  The only conceivable way to do this is to cause a negative curve in spacetime that opposes the gravity with some sort of negative mass matter (like is proposed for the [Alcubierre warp drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) ), but the existence of such is theoretical.

Comment: Even if it did exist (this has never been observed anywhere in the universe), the amount of it necessary to counteract such extreme curvature would require a mass close to the mass of the containing black hole.  Thus, it would have to have such extreme positive curvature at its singularity that the anti-gravity would blow the planet around it apart.  The mathematics simply do not allow for anything like the OPs question to happen, and we trust that math with very high confidence, since it has passed every experiment thrown at it.

Comment: No I mean some kind of material that controls the very laws of physics. We cannot be sure of such a materials nonexistance, becuase if it did, we might never be aware that we were living in a hollow planent with inverted gravity. Changing the laws of physics might change it across all space time akin to changing the channel on the tv.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck what you are talking about is in the realm of fantasy and fiction, not science.  This question was originally tagged "science-based" when I wrote this answer, so the scope of my answer is within that constraint.  Since other people address the fantasy aspects related to this, I am not amending my answer to account for that.  What you propose is simply not possible, even in theory.

Comment: @Cody alright, but to put it lightly, we cannot confirm or deny the existence of certain 'things'. We cannot confirm or deny the existence of time travel, multiverse, or even something as simple as there being 4 dimensions (though they are highly in doubt). How can we say that there isn't a way to escape or remain intact and balanced in a black hole? Perhaps there exists a particle that gravity does not apply to, yet has gravity.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, “Perhaps there exists a particle that gravity does not apply to, yet has gravity”. That sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're mistaken in at least some sense. First, consider a really huge black hole, to sidestep the issue of spaghettification for a while. In this case it's well-known that it's possible to cross the event horizon without noticing anything, and continue to experience time inside the black hole (although your velocity is constrained to always have an inward component, that's not the same as "can't orbit" or "only one direction exists"). I don't know of anything that would prevent you from colliding with an object that crossed the event horizon after you did, either.

Comment: In short, there's no reason why someone couldn't throw something after you and hit you with it after you were inside a black hole; they wouldn't be able to observe the collision, but you would. However it is true that where the premise of the question breaks down is planets having a stable orbit, or people living *for any extended time* inside the event horizon.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I mean that the particle cannot be moved by gravity (i.e. gravitational force cannot pull it. this is not some kind of super-mass or anything. It's just somehow immune to the pull) but still has a gravitational pull on objects around it (so it can be used to build a planet that people live on, but can sit inside an event horizon without moving... for as long as the particle has it's special quality)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck yeah, that's a contradiction, unless you go around changing the definitions of things like "force" and "gravity". You can't interact with a field while also *not* interacting with the field. It goes beyond "not possible" to "not meaningful".

Comment: "Everything inside will not retain a form recognizable to us." You should make it more clear that you mean "inside the singularity" or at least "inside the spaghettification radius". Everything just inside the event horizon, but at a suitable distance from the singularity, will be just fine and completely normal, as long as we (observers) are inside the EH as well.

Comment: @hobbs you mean it isn't meaningful to say something pulls while not being pulled? I agree it's an unlikely thing to exist in the universe, but it hardly seems in the realm of fantasy. To me it seems like a logical thing to think of. "we have this thing called gravity. Now what particle ***doesn't*** have gravity"

Comment: @TheGreatDuck free photons, despite being massless and having no gravitational pull of their own, still respond to the gravitational pull of objects with mass.  [They follow "straight lines" (aka geodesics) in spacetime, but because spacetime is curved, those lines don't appear straight to us and our Euclidian understanding of things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3GVVkPb3OI).  Gravity applies to everything.  All of your arguments thus far seem to follow "We don't know everything, therefore it is possible", completely ignoring what we do know and what we are able to rule out because of it.

Comment: @Cody Look, the asker gave us a premise and it is our responsibility to assume that premise is true when answering. I'm not saying they exist, but my point is that we do not really know for sure. If you asked someone 100-200 years ago they'd say there was no such thing as a particle smaller than an atom... people proved that wrong with electrons and protons.... and even more so with quarks. We do not know precisely what particle causes gravity. For all we know, a particle 10 levels deeper than quarks emanates gravity, and the only reason we believe gravity exists is because that particle......

Comment: (continued)... is contained within 99.99999% of all quarks in the universe in ratios that make sense. Hence, there might be a way to remove gravity. I believe it is not true, but I think it would be more in the realm of science-fiction, not fantasy. Sometimes, science based answers ask us to make things up. This is one of those situations, and can we *truly* answer this question? No, not really. We just assume so as it makes the most logical sense.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest method would be a sabot attack.  If you hi-jack one of the enemies ships and know how it gets back to the home planet, it should be possible to plant a bomb/virus on there that knocks out the safe zone generators.  Once that's gone, the planet gets sucked into the black hole.

Destroy one planet and you could well have a political/emotional victory.  Faced with a third of their population (or the loss of their primary planet), they will need to negotiate an outcome.  Losing a third of your resources (or centre of government) is pretty severe.

If they don't face up to defeat, the same thing might happen, or all outgoing ships might well get destroyed.

Comment: That is a nice simple idea, a crew sacrificing their life, a planet destroyed in a second after turning of the safe zone, very cruel.  The problem is after the first planet they would find a defensive also the enemy need to find the path for the wormholes maybe they can destroy 1 planet like that.

Comment: Black holes don’t “suck”.  They have gravity like anything else.

Comment: @JDługosz I was generalising for dramatic effect.  The lack of the green zone would still result in the planet being obliterated by the black hole.

Comment: The planet with its safe zone deactivated, is already inside the black hole. The gravitational forces inside that BH will then destroy the planet. It does need to be sucked in.

Comment: I was puzzled about the phrase "sabot attack" as attacking planets inside a BH with wooden shoes shows ingenuity, but I couldn't help wondering about its effectiveness. Admittedly hurling millions of sabots at relativistic velocities into the BH might destroy the safe zone planets. Then I realised! What you meant was: "The simplest method would be sabotage." Throwing sabots or wooden shoes into factory machinery gave us the word "sabotage". Full marks for knowing the origin of the word. Plus one for the method.

Comment: @a4android Well, I had another purpose for using that word.  To me, a sabot is a container, carrier, or outer projectile for something explosive.  The bomb here would be contained within a native ship and thus be hidden from view.

Comment: Ah yes! Quite right! I had forgotten about that usage of the word. Both meanings apply in this scenario. There's always a way around the best defences. A cunning plan can do the trick.

Comment: Learning something new everday :D.

Comment: @JDługosz: Ah, but gravity sucks in space/time!

Comment: @JDługosz Actually black holes do suck. There is a region outside event horizon where every free-fall/ballistic orbit will enter the black hole, and you need to use propulsion to not get sucked in. Additionally, inside event horizon, direction of time is towards the singularity, so hitting it is inevitable, and I'd call that quite extreme sucking.

Comment: @a4android How can you *target* anything inside event horizon, when you can't see it? Except if you are between it and singularity, in which case it's kinda too late to hit it at least without some kind of worm hole technology.

Answer (score 12):

Science has no answers for you.  We have no empirical way to test hypotheses about what happens inside an event horizon, so the best we can do is *literally* an educated guess.  Steven Hawking recently made one of those guesses about what happens inside the first few nanometers, after years of work, and the scientific community is still debating the validity of his claims.

Your options are:

- **Spin the planet** - A spinning black hole eventually loses energy to Hawking Radiation and gets smaller.  Eventually such a black hole can dissipate.  So, if you're patient enough to wait the quadrillions of years for it to dissipate, you can do something to the planets... if they're still there.
- **Subterfuge** - Convince one of the members of that species to enter the wormholes and break down whatever magic is making this whole thing work.
- **Magic** - This is one of those infamous "I invented a rock so heavy even God cannot lift it, now help me move it" sort of problems.  You invented a technology which is so advanced that it literally operates beyond the known laws of physics.  Use that same technology to attack the planets.  When you invent rocks so heavy that even God cannot lift them, it is *entirely* plausible that said rock also cannot be lifted by science either.  That's an inherent risk in such handwaving.

I highly recommend reading the blog post on [Sanderson's First Law of Magic](http://brandonsanderson.com/sandersons-first-law/).  What you describe qualifies as magic by Arthur C. Clarke's definition of magic, so you should plan around following Sanderson's First Law:

> Sanderson’s First Law of Magics: An author’s ability to solve conflict with magic is DIRECTLY PROPORTIONAL to how well the reader understands said magic.

Sanderson's law doesn't limit the options you have for solving this issue, but it does point out that you're going to have to make sure the reader is *very* comfortable with it before resolving major plot points using it.

Answer (score 5):

**Use Their Own Weapon**

Your best bet is to learn how they maintain a planet inside a blackhole. Assuming equal technology/science level, your scientists and engineers most likely could reverse the method.

**Espionage**

If your race is far inferior in technology and you can't reverse engineer the method, then you try to capture a ship, plant some kind of a GPS/analytic device and send it back to analyze the road.

**Antimatter Missiles**

In theory antimatter doesn't destroy a blackhole completely but as far as we assume, big powerful antimatter missiles will create huge explosions inside the blackhole but even then the energy won't escape and the blackhole will grow larger.

Answer (score 3):

Cover the surrounding of the black hole with antimatter dust. The dust particles will fall into the black hole, and since they are everywhere, statistically *some* of them will hit the planets, and a matter-antimatter explosion even of a few grams of antimatter will release as much energy as an atomic bomb.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the problem that the tidal forces of the black hole will destroy any missile you can throw at them.  Thus the only solution I see is to throw a missile that is immune to tides--another black hole.

You still have the basically-impossible targeting problem of knowing where the enemy planets are hiding.  However, you don't need a direct hit--all you need to do is overload the gravity generators that are protecting the enemy planets and their own black hole will finish the job.

Comment: If you have a sufficiently large black hole (perhaps the size of the ones at the galactic core), the tidal forces will be minimal around the event horizon. Planets could orbit the singularity in the space between the event horizon and singularity, but the physical conditions in the space might not be conducive for biological life.

Comment: @Thucydides Inside event horizon, space and time sort of "switch places", so you can't have orbits there without magic tech. As surely as time moves forward outside event horizon, everything inside moves towards singularity; there is no stopping or going back, any more than there is stopping or reversing time in normal space.

Comment: @hyde But what about a rapidly rotating black hole?  Don't you get a second event horizon, inside of which space & time have once again switched so an orbit would be possible?  You'll still need some incredibly powerful gravity generators to keep the tides from eating your planet, though.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Right you are, I had forgotten that property of rotating black holes... hmm.

Answer (score 1):

Find a way to divert a neutron star into the black hole.  They are super dense already, and would add dramatically to the mass of the black hole, and would change the size of the black hole and the radius of the event horizon.  Then the aliens planet would be actually inside, or further inside, and perhaps their technology might not be able to adapt to or overcome that difference.

Comment: Density has nothing to do with it, it is all about the mass.  OP doesn't specify the mass of the black hole in which these planets "exist", but if it can encompass planetary orbits then it must be at least a few astronomical units across.  A neutron star with at most [3 solar masses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star#Properties) would barely make change in a black hole that size, already millions of solar masses.  Moreover, stuff falls into black holes all the time.  Even if there was a way to orbit inside a black hole, they would have to account for that or else be destroyed anyway.

Comment: What about finding a way to divert a black hole to it them? Or grow a nearby black hole bigger? Im sure two black holes colliding would do something?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck it would release a ton of energy as gravitational waves, gamma rays, x rays that would destroy whoever was outside sending the other black hole in.  What happens on the inside of the two black holes is unknown.  You can't simply "divert a black hole", the mass of a naturally occuring BH is [at minimum 10x the mass of the sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#Physical_properties), you simply cannot harness enough energy to move an object that size.

Comment: No, I mean grow the smaller black hole by tossing a neutron star into it, and hope that the increased radius causes it to fall into the bigger black hole.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck That would only have an effect on a similarly small black hole, which would have hardly any effect on the huge hole. Of course, if you have enough time, you could simply toss entire galaxies in the black hole, but it's unlikely you would have enough time anyway. We're talking on the order of millions or maybe billions of years - if you plan on such time scales, you can just ignore the threat alltogether - it will disappear on its own as the universe keeps expanding :)

Comment: @Luaan a smaller black hole's radius will increase faster than the bigger black hole. This post suggested throwing a neutron star in, so I'm suggesting a black hole as that might produce a more violent reaction than just the black hole consuming more matter. Growing a small black hole 1000 km in the hopes it falls in vs growing a giant black hole 1 km in the hopes it sucks things in seems pretty logical if we are going the route of "chuck things in to try and destabilize the planet"

Answer (score 0):

**Only a god can kill a god**

What you could use is the classical **traitor** scenario. If your alien race is so advanced, i higlhy doubt there is any way for an inferior race to take them in a frontal way.

So what humanity (or whatever inferior specie) need to destroy their planets is an inside man. Some kind of pariah from this advanced race who just happens to hate that much is own kind that he will help you gladly to wipe them out (did anybody said Avatar ?).

As far as **how** he would help humanity to destroy his own kind, i guess he could use his great knowledge in blackholes to create a small one within the safe zone of a planet. I'm pretty they wouldn't have planned that

Comment: Nice idea but the problem is that this race is not like us. They remeber anything and they can use everything heard or watched, that is why this race is super advanced. But the race does not have a conzept of power or war, they live to study and understand the whole universe so they make experiments in the universe often destroying other species, and now some guys want to stop them playing around with us like we were insects.

Comment: So they are like very very smart and curious children ?

Comment: Yeah and live is not important for them so if they try something out in the universe sometimes other races die, so they have to stop them. They understand the act of war but for them is it pointless, they dont have an army or weapons, they seek for something bigger.

Comment: So maybe you can paradox them out to hell ? Tell them humanity knows something bigger, way more badass than anything they could have encountered in their seek for knowledge. But to got this they have to give humanity some kind technologies that we could use to destroy them. Obviously you don't tell them that you want technology X to destroy them, just that you want it for reasons. 
As they don't trust in war they won't think of humanity using this set oftechnology to get them out.

Comment: That would be a way but i think a race like that would not be so easy to fool. Even fooling a human like this is difficult, fooling such a race would be huge. They dont talk to us also because we are not important for them.

Comment: Well if you don't have more firepower than them, you can't outsmart them and there is nobody from their side to help you... then i can't recall any historical battle/war that as been won in this situation. It's like if the smurfs were fighting a moon sized M1 Abrams who just happens to be driving from point A to point b without noticing them ^^ I hope someone smarter than me will help you because i'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

No one knows what exactly happens after you pass event horizon (which is just outside the black hole, which is point of no return. Since it's point of no return we don't know happens inside).

> Most likely enemy missiles will transform into information or some kind of dense mass(energy) before hit your planet which is inside event horizon. So enemy can't aim or destroy your planet. Not only that they'll never know if they hit the target or not after random attack. 
>   Of course in case enemy master same technology as yours then can send probes into inside event horizon then they can aim and send missile that withstand even horizon.

Comment: Note that once anything crosses the event horizon, it is expected to be traveling faster than light and therefore moving back in time instead of forward.  What could withstand this time reversal?

Comment: @user6030 Umm, I'm not sure why you would think that. The topology of the spacetime is simply such that there is no path forward in time that leads out of the black hole. That says nothing about the speed you'll have inside the black hole (relative to what?). The black holes we're observing certainly don't appear to be accelerating the infalling matter to anywhere close to the speed of light (though obviously, we only see what's outside of the horizon), and I don't see any reason to believe that would happen, much less *faster* than light travel, which doesn't fit GR at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix magic and popular physics, introduce the idea of gravitational wave 'earthquakes'.  The people on those planets may be magically protected from a constant gravitational field, but a gravitational wave disturbs that constant field and squashes the planets into egg shapes, causing earthquakes, eruptions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Chuck another Black Hole at it.**

First of all, technology that can protect an entire planet from the harsh environment of a black hole (not to mention the extreme gravity!) must be pretty sweet. All infalling matter would have already been accelerated to relativistic speeds by the time it got to the planet. Basically, a missile (even an antimatter one) would be nothing compared to what the planets already encounter every day from just in-falling dust and extreme blue-shifted radiation.

Now, if its possible at all to destroy these planets, colliding the blackhole with another blackhole just might be able to crush these planets. If we assume that the black hole in your diagram can fit 10 earths side by side inside it, and we use a [formula from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole), we can compute that your black hole has a mass approximately equal to 27,000 solar masses. This is about 1/4 the size of the smallest super-massive blackholes. In the black hole collision detected last year, about 4.6% of the mass of the two black holes colliding was released. If we chuck another black hole similar to the size of the black hole in your diagram at it, and we assume a mass loss of 1%, 540 solar masses of gravitational energy will be released in the collision. For the sake of your aliens, I hope that their gravity shields can protect them from that much energy.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is specifically based on Destroying the planet thus in any manner we will not be able to visit or colonize the planet afterwards.
If we can somehow simulate an experiment which increases the **hawking radiation** on event horizon the black hole will eventually lose mass and destruct. 
Exponential growth of particle and antiparticle pair creation will speed up the process.

[Hawking radiation (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation)